# What can make a SQL Server DB exhibit a cyclic CPU usage behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, msmq, cpu-usage

I have a system that is processing messages from an MSMQ queue (using multiple processes to do the processing).

Each message processing implies reading some rows, and making 3 updates and 1 insert. I'm processing around 60 messages per sec with this system.

What is puzzling me is that when for whatever reason, the queue has a buildup of messages, and the system is working as fast as it can to process messages, the CPU usage exhibits a cycle with peaks of 95%-100% and valleys of 50%-45%. This behavior holds even when I add more processes to do the processing.

Is it expected of SQL Server to show that behavior when the workload implies row insertion and updates (I'm thinking cache flushing, etc.)? Maybe it's got something to do with the host (this is running on Hyper-V, instead of on real hardware)?

Here's a link to a perfmon run: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2200654/sql_perf_000001.rar

Comment: Collect the `Physical Disk(*)\*` and all the `SQL Server:*\*` performance counters, post them here, and then we can discuss.

Comment: This is the first time I use logman...and I'm having trouble creating the report ('At least one of the input binary log files contains fewer than two data samples'). I guess this is a question inside a question, isn't it? =)

Comment: is it a named SQL Server instance or a default instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason of the strange behavior: lack of memory. When I added the 'Memory: Page Reads/sec' counter, the valleys coincided with times of high page faulting.

Thanks for your answers (now the question seems silly, I'll ask for more memory :).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how to start logman counter trace for some relevant counters, with 10s collection interval, for a default SQL Server instance:

```
@echo off
del %temp%\sql_perf*.blg
logman delete sql_perf
logman create counter sql_perf -f bin -si 10 -o %temp%\sql_perf.blg -c "\Processor(_Total)\*" "\Physical Disk(*)\*" "\Process(*)\*" "\SQLServer:Access Methods\*" "\SQLServer:Databases(*)\*" "\SQLServer:Memory Manager\*" "\SQLServer:SQL Statistics\*" "\SQLServer:Wait Statistics\*" "\SQLServer:Transactions\*"
logman start sql_perf
```

Named instances change the counter category name from "SQLServer:..." to ":..."

The uploaded performance counters are missing the Phsyical Disk counters so the IO analysis is incomplete, but one think standing out is that the % CPU usage is an exact match of the SQL Server transaction/sec and batches/sec:

[image: EBUS performance counters]

Note how the red line (% CPU) follows exactly the shape of the green line (Transactions/sec) and also the blue line (Batches/sec). This indicates that the spikes are entirely driven by the application behavior. Simply said, the SQL Server spikes in CPU (and also on IO write read, the purple line) simply because your application spikes requests every 3 minutes or so.

Comment: I've added the trace. I don't know what to search on it, but I do see the pattern I've described...

Comment: That correlation in Tx/sec and CPU usage is what I can't explain. My app has 8 worker *processes*, and the only things that they share are an MSMQ queue (from which they take work) and the SQL Server instance which they update. I have spikes of 100 messages processed and valleys of 50 messages processed and each messsage is practically the same. To take this snapshot I let the queue build up, and so my workers should be working at full speed and yet they don't seem to use all CPU. I'll try to add the other counters (I've used your cmdline, they are missing there?). Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Look for MSMQ counters too and them as well. It may well be that the pattern is driven by the flux of messages coming in and then you have to analyze the message sources, maybe they have this pattern of *sending* in spikes.

Comment: The command line had a typo indeed, the counter is named `PhysicalDisk` (no space). For a correct spelling of Windows counters, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms803998.aspx For SQL Server counters see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190382.aspx For MSMQ counters see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771098%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I've ruled out MSMQ message flux by letting the messages build up. Also I've stopped the message producer and seen no CPU usage (but I didn't do that during the trace collection, I'll do that for the next attempt).

Answer (score 0):

Check the rest - could it be you hit acheckpoint and thus processing slows down until the dirty pages are written to the database?

Comment: That was my first thought, but the thing is, I don't see disk activity that coincides with the peaks or valleys...maybe I'm looking at the wrong counter?